# Subscribe an Amazon SNS topic using AWS Lambda fn that is sns.subscribe()?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I want to send an SNS subscription request to a Topic for email subscription,
As I'm new to Lambda, Can you please let me know what libraries needs to be imported and what functions needs to be triggered.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. Import Boto3 Package
2. Create a Reference to SNS Boto
3. Create a SNS Topic
4. Create a Email Susbcriber to that SNS Topic.
   (make sure you follow the indentation in python. It a running code)

   ```
    import boto3
    snsClient =  boto3.client('sns')

    def lambda_handler(event, context):
     topicName = "myFirstTopic"
     emailId= "yourname@company.com"
     #creating Topic and if it already created with the specified name, that topic's ARN is returned without creating a new topic..
     snsArn = createSNSTopic(topicName)   
     #crearting a subscriber for the specified SNS Toic
     snsEndpointSusbcribe(snsArn,emailId)


    #Function to create SNS Topic 
    def createSNSTopic(topicName):
     try:
         response = snsClient.create_topic(
            Name=topicName
         )

         print(response['TopicArn'])
         return response['TopicArn']
     except Exception as ex:
         print(ex)

   #Function to create SNS Subscriber for that Topic
   def snsEndpointSusbcribe(snsArn,emailId):
    response = snsClient.subscribe(
        #
        TopicArn=snsArn,
        Protocol='email',
        Endpoint=emailId,
    )
   ```

Comment: Thanks Bhavuk, what do you mean by "Create a Reference to SNS Boto"

Comment: Im gettting syntax error while running this code

Comment: Line no 2 , snsClient =  boto3.client('sns'). and please type the error here..!! (Make sure your indentation is proper and you have IAM permissions) @vinay rathore

Comment: Endpoint response body before transformations: {"errorMessage": "Syntax error in module 'lambda_function'"}

Comment: Not sure, you have done or not. If not, please reach out to me at bhavukbhardwaj03@gmail.com

Comment: Hi @bhavuk Thanks, It worked after giving proper roles to lambda , Do you know the best way to unsubscribe a topic from lambda when we have email address and topic arn. Seems like it needs subscriber ARN which is tuff to iterate

Comment: Hi @vinayrathore, I am glad that the above code worked for you. Please mark it as an accepted answer or upvote that. And when it comes to your second question which you asked now, you can open another question in stackoverflow with that. But surely there is no one-way solution, there is so many workarounds which you have to do. I will try to ans there. You can comment the link for your second question.